# Highcharts passing variable to tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I am trying to pass a variable to my tooltip using `setData`.

Here is a piece of my code explaining how I am setting the chart data, this code doesn't pass the `sensorValue` to my tooltip yet:

```
nitrogenDioxide = [];
$.each(data['NO2'], function(key, value) {
    nitrogenDioxide.push([value.ts * 1000, value.rating]);
});

chart_2_1.series[0].setData(nitrogenDioxide);
chart_2_1.series[0].update({name:'Nitrogen Dioxide'}, true);
```

Here is the code I used to create my tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
            var tooltipcontent = '<b>' + moment.unix((this.points[0].key / 1000)).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"); + '</b>';
            tooltipcontent += '<table style="width:100%">';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                console.log(this);
                tooltipcontent += '<tr><td>' + this.y.toLocaleString() + '</td></tr>';
                tooltipcontent += '<tr><td>' + sensorValue + '</td></tr>';
            });

            tooltipcontent += '</table>';
            return tooltipcontent;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have a variable called `sensorValue` in my tooltip. In the foreach loop I have a rating value (y-axis) and a sensor value. I want to pass that sensor value to me tooltip.

I have seen multiple ways of doing this online but none of them set the data the way I do, they do it like so:

```
new Highcharts.Chart( {
...,
series: [ {
    name: 'Foo',
    data: [
        {
            y : 3,
            myData : 'firstPoint'
        },
        {
            y : 7,
            myData : 'secondPoint'
        },
        {
            y : 1,
            myData : 'thirdPoint'
        }
    ]
} ]
```

} );

I have tried something like this but didn't know how to call this extra value in the tooltip:

```
nitrogenDioxide = [];
$.each(data['NO2'], function(key, value) {
    nitrogenDioxide.push([value.ts * 1000, value.rating, value.value]);
});
```

In the above code I have pushed the sensor value into the `nitrogenDioxide[]` array.

I have tried my best to explain what I am trying to do, in my head the explanation makes sense but if it doesnt to you please let me know. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly what is your issue and the demo posted below will be helpful for you.

When an array with an additional value is passed (sensorValue in your case) it can be retrieved **inside formatter** using this approach:

- get hovered point index: `this.point.index`
- use the point index to get additional value from `this.series.userOptions.data` array

**Code:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      var point = this.point,
        series = this.series,
        pointIndex = point.index,
        text,
        additionalValue;

      text = '<span style="color:' +
        this.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' +
        series.name +
        ': <b>' +
        this.y +
        '</b><br/>';

      additionalValue =
        series.userOptions.data[pointIndex][2];

      text += '<br> Additional value: ' +
        additionalValue;

      return text;
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      [1, 2, 'aaa'], // 'aaa' is an additional value
      [2, 5, 'bbb'],
      [3, 9, 'ccc']
    ]
  }],
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3g6om1fw/1/